# Задача с Codewars на строки и массивы (JS)

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки, функции, циклы

Возникла сложность с задачей на Codewars, прошу помочь. Сама задача:
You are given a string of letters and an array of numbers.
The numbers indicate positions of letters that must be removed, in order, starting from the beginning of the array.
After each removal the size of the string decreases (there is no empty space).
Return the only letter left.

Example:

```
let str = "zbk", arr = [0, 1]
    str = "bk", arr = [1]
    str = "b", arr = []
    return 'b'
```

Notes
The given string will never be empty.
The length of the array is always one less than the length of the string.
All numbers are valid.
There can be duplicate letters and numbers.

Мое решение:

```
    function lastSurvivor(letters, coords) {
    for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    letter = letters.slice(coords[i], coords[i] + 1);
    return letters.replace(letter, '');
    }
    }
        
    console.log(lastSurvivor('zbk', [0, 1]));
```

Результат должен быть 'b', но у меня выходит 'bk'.
В чем тут проблема никак не пойму.
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Для начала, почему у вас return в цикле находится? вы же сразу возвращаете значение, а возвращается 'bk' т.к вы возвращаете вырезанное значение letter = letters.slice(1, 1+1)

Comment: А еще у Вас удаляется не символ на конкретной позиции, а первое вхождение символа по заданной позиции. Т.е. 'abacaba', [2] у Вас вернет "bacaba", а должна "abcaba"

Comment: предположу, что строка вам дана не для того, чтобы из нее что-то удалять. ее вообще трогать не надо, а на основании данного массива вычислить искомый индекс.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function lastSurvivor(string, indices) {
  [...new Set(indices)].forEach((index) => {
    string = string.slice(0, index) + string.slice(index + 1);
  });
  
  return string;
}

console.log(
  lastSurvivor('zbk', [0, 1]), // b
  lastSurvivor('bk', [0]), // k
  lastSurvivor('jkj', [2, 1, 1, 1]) // j
);
```

Answer (score -2):

Это вне диапазона: вы не проследили свою логику? Вы перебираете весь coords список для каждого элемента в списке. С точки зрения структуры у вас есть вложенный цикл, в котором проблема предполагает только один цикл.

У вас также есть серьезная ошибка в том, что вы берете значение из coords, а затем используете его в качестве индекса в списке.

Избавьтесь от while; просто перебрать заданные координаты.

```js
new_letters = list(letters)
for pos in coords:
    new_letters.pop(pos)            

return ''.join(new_letters)
```

решение от: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67605942/last-survivor-codewars